# To be up for the task

Tags: meaning

For the Coach Karter movie:

> -- Nice to see you again, Mr. Karter.
>   -- You too ma'am. If the offer still stands I'd like to coach the team.
>   -- Well, I hope you're up for the task. These young men need discipline.

I don't understand the exact meaning of that up for the task here. I could guess that it has something to do with `be awared`, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be *up for the task* means to be willing to do it, often in spite of the difficulties or challenges it poses.

To be "up to the task" means to be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Being "up for the task" is an [idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom). "Being up for" is like saying "able to perform the task or job". The "task" in this case refers to the job of coaching the team.

She is saying "I hope you are able to perform the task of coaching these young men."

Sometimes it is also said as "up to the task".

Comment: Downvoted - See TRomano's answer.

Comment: Yeah, TRomano said it better.